# Read json files from folder, get specific key value, write the key value to seperate text files in folder

Tags: python, json

I need to extract value of key 'text' in multiple json files and write the value to separate text files in UTF-8 format.

there are 2,900 json files and I have imported json, os, glob to my environment running python 3.7 64-bit, W10, VS studio, set current working directory to folder where json files exist

python: This successfully writes key 'text' value from one json file 'j_news1' to one text file 'j_news1.txt:

```
with open('j_news1.txt', 'w') as json_file:
json.dump(j_news1['text'], json_file)
```

--I have created a filelist for all files in cwd:

```
filelist = glob.glob(',/*.json')
```

code that takes filelist and opens-read, open-writes for all json in folder works:

```
for fname in filelist:
       FI = open(fname, 'r')
       FO = open(fname.replace('json', 'txt'), 'w')
       for line in FI:
          FO.write(line)
```

what I can't find is how to extract just key 'text' and write that to the separate text files.

sample json from file:

```
pprint.pprint(j_news1)
{'author': '',
 'crawled': '2018-02-02T15:37:30.069+02:00',
 'entities': {'locations': [{'name': 'us', 'sentiment': 'none'}],
              'organizations': [{'name': 'mins ago cnbc',
                                 'sentiment': 'negative'}],
              'persons': [{'name': 'kate rogers', 'sentiment': 'negative'}]},
 'external_links': [],
 'highlightText': '',
 'highlightTitle': '',
 'language': 'english',
 'locations': [],
 'ord_in_thread': 0,
 'organizations': [],
 'persons': [],
 'published': '2018-02-02T14:39:00.000+02:00',
 'text': "Police officer shortage growing problem in US 54 Mins Ago CNBC's "
         'Kate Rogers reports police departments around the country are facing '
         'a major challenge recruiting and retaining staff.',
 'thread': {'country': 'US',
            'domain_rank': 767,
            'main_image': 'https://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/img/editorial/2018/02/02/104984906-6ED2-SB-020218-PoliceShortage.600x400.jpg',
            'participants_count': 0,
            'performance_score': 0,
            'published': '2018-02-02T14:39:00.000+02:00',
            'replies_count': 0,
            'section_title': 'Latest Video',
            'site': 'cnbc.com',
            'site_full': 'www.cnbc.com',
            'site_section': 'http://www.cnbc.com/id/100004038/device/rss/rss.html',
            'site_type': 'news',
            'social': {'facebook': {'comments': 0, 'likes': 1, 'shares': 1},
                       'gplus': {'shares': 0},
                       'linkedin': {'shares': 0},
                       'pinterest': {'shares': 0},
                       'stumbledupon': {'shares': 0},
                       'vk': {'shares': 0}},
            'spam_score': 0.0,
            'title': 'Police officer shortage growing problem in US',
            'title_full': '',
            'url': 'https://www.cnbc.com/video/2018/02/02/police-officer-shortage-growing-problem-in-us.html',
            'uuid': 'b55dd31fa1152ca4b7fff55bc143129add534a41'},
 'title': 'Police officer shortage growing problem in US',
 'url': 'https://www.cnbc.com/video/2018/02/02/police-officer-shortage-growing-problem-in-us.html',
 'uuid': 'b55dd31fa1152ca4b7fff55bc143129add534a41'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple: [json.load(fp)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) will load json file to python object and then just extract `'text'` from it.

```
import json
json_object = json.load(FI)
FO.write(json_object['text'])
```

and that's it.

Comment: thank you makozaki,  I added encoding = 'UTF-8' to open statement and now I have a solution, very much appreciated

Comment: Glad I helped, if it solves your question then you could accept my answer ;)